# Python: why is a boolean statement printed as True but returned as None?

Tags: python, return, boolean

I have the below code and cannot figure out why the return value of doesNumExistInList() is None.
The PRINT statement just before the RETURN statement prints True but the return value is None. Why?

I tried explicitly typing the return value into boolean but didn't help.

I know this can be shortened to a one-liner with print(b in a). That's not the point.

```
# Write a function that takes an ordered list of numbers (a list where the elements are in order from smallest to largest) and another number. 
# The function decides whether or not the given number is inside the list and returns (then prints) an appropriate boolean.

import math

# expecting an ordered list
def doesNumExistInList(num, listOfNum):
    # given the recursion below we're gonna end up here at some point
    if len(listOfNum) == 1:
        print (num == listOfNum[0]) # prints True
        return (num == listOfNum[0]) # returns None - why??
    elif len(listOfNum) == 2:
        print (num == listOfNum[0] or num == listOfNum[1])
        return (num == listOfNum[0] or num == listOfNum[1])

    # recursive logic
    half = math.ceil(len(listOfNum) / 2)
    if num <= listOfNum[half-1]:
        doesNumExistInList(num, listOfNum[:(half-1)])
    else:
        doesNumExistInList(num, listOfNum[half:])

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = 6
print (a)
print (b)
print(doesNumExistInList(b, a))
```

Comment: Your recursive logic needs to have a `return` statement, too.

Comment: more specifically `return doesNumExistInList(...`

Comment: Yes, that works. Still, why?

Comment: since the function didn't have a return, a `return None` is assumed at the end. So the recursive stack has a boolean return at the end but it is not carried through the return stack.